# Проблема с клонированием формы, содержащей select2

Tags: jquery, select2

При использовании плагина select2 столкнулся с проблемой клонирования, а именно - новые блоки являются неактивными.

На данный момент имеется такой код js

```
var Count = 1;
$(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first-child'),
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
            newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone(true)).appendTo(controlForm);


        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
            .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
            .html('<div id="rectangle"></div>');


    }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
    {
        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

html

```
<form method="post" id="data">
   <div class="entry input-group col-xs-3">
   <input class="name" name="name[]" type="text" placeholder="Введите название" />
   <input class="cost" name="cost[]" type="text" placeholder="Введите стоимость" />

   <select class="select-item-1 select-block" name="Mat[]">
      <option selected hidden style='display: none' value="asd">Выберите материал</option>
      <?foreach ($Mark as $value): ?>
          <option value="<?=$value['id_m']?>"><?=$value['M_Name']?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
   </select>

   <select class="select-item-2 select-block" name="Prod[]">
      <option selected hidden style='display: none' value="asd">Выберите продукт</option>
      <?foreach ($Prod as $value): ?>
          <option value="<?=$value['id_p']?>"><?=$value['P_Name']?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
   </select>

   <div class="btn-add">
      <div class="cross"></div>
   </div>
```

```
<form method="post" class="buttons" action="<?=base_url('test/index/');?>">
    <button class="btn btn" type="submit" form="data" name="PIadd" value="SendOrd">Добавить</button>
    <button class="btn reset" type="reset">Сбросить</button>
</form>
```

Пока искал в интернете, наткнулся на этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17381913). Так же есть [такой вариант](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDa2knZwoUc), но тут показывают как делать для одного элемента и не совсем понятно, как его применить в моем случае.
Собственно, сам вопрос - как должен выглядеть сам js код, чтобы блоки были активными? А так же как правильно добавить счетчик для каждого нового селекта (нужно для последующей правильной обработки, т.к. будет установлен атрибут multiple)?

UPD: Решил проблему. Привожу код, может кому пригодиться

```
<script>
    var Count = 1;
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".entry").children("select").select2();
        $(".btn-add").click(function () {
            $(".entry")
                .children("select")
                .select2("destroy")
                .removeAttr('data-live-search')
                .removeAttr('data-select2-id')
                .removeAttr('aria-hidden')
                .removeAttr('tabindex');
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var controlForm = $('.controls form:first-child'),
                currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone(true)).appendTo(controlForm);

            newEntry.find('input').val('');
            controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
                .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                .html('<div id="rectangle"></div>');

            $(".entry").children("select").each(function () {
                $(this).select2({
                    theme: "classic",
                    "language": {
                        "noResults": function(){
                            return "По запросу ничего не найдено";
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
        {
            $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".select-block").each(function(i) {
         $(this).select2();
    });
```

Comment: Увы, этот код дал тот же результат. В зависимости от того, куда ставил, получал либо неактивные блоки (конец скрипта), либо блоки, где при добавлении новой строки select2 слетает с предыдущего (середина скрипта).